# Ocupo agregarle a esta matriz un metodo que sume los numeros aleatorios que genero pero no se como hacerlo

Tags: java, matrices

Solo necesitaría agregar una función que recorra la matriz y retorne La suma de los números alojados en toda la matriz.

Sería de mucha ayuda si pudieran agregarla porque he estado pegado con ese ya que realmente no se como hacerlo muchas gracias

```
public class Matriz {

    private int[][] m;

    public Matriz() {
        this.m = new int[10][10];
        this.llenarM();

    }

    public void llenarM() {

        for (int f = 0; f < this.m.length; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.m.length; c++) {
                this.m[f][c] = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);

            }
        }
    }

    public void mostrarM() {
        for (int f = 0; f < this.m.length; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.m.length; c++) {
                System.out.print(this.formato(this.m[f][c] + "") + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public String formato(String dato) {

        int tam = dato.length();
        String salida = "";

        if (tam == 1) {
            salida = dato + " ";
        } else {
            salida = dato;
        }
        return salida;

    }
```

Comment: con la misma estructura de  tu método `llenar()` podrias usar una variable que sume los valores de tu array bidimensional  `suma+=m[f][c]` ,desde luego este nuevo metodo seria de tipo `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes incluso generarla como una propiedad de tu clase.

```
public class Matriz {

    private int[][] m;
    private int suma = 0;
    ...
```

Y en tu método `llenar` irla sumando.

```
public void llenarM() {

    for (int f = 0; f < this.m.length; f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < this.m.length; c++) {
             int numero =(int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
             this.m[f][c] = numero;
             this.suma += numero;
        }
    }
}
```

Y al final nada más tienes que generarle el getter

```
public int getSuma(){
    return this.suma;
}
```

El código completo es

```
public class Matriz {

    private int[][] m;
    private int suma = 0;

    public Matriz() {
        this.m = new int[10][10];
        this.llenarM();

    }

    public void llenarM() {

        for (int f = 0; f < this.m.length; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.m.length; c++) {
                int numero =(int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
                this.m[f][c] = numero;
                this.suma += numero;

            }
        }
    }

    public void mostrarM() {
        for (int f = 0; f < this.m.length; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.m.length; c++) {
                System.out.print(this.formato(this.m[f][c] + "") + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public String formato(String dato) {

        int tam = dato.length();
        String salida = "";

        if (tam == 1) {
            salida = dato + " ";
        } else {
            salida = dato;
        }
        return salida;

    }

    public int getSuma(){
        return this.suma;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Okal-CR Era innecesaria tu edición, ¿por qué quisiste borrar el apartado de "código completo"?